# Validar login en servlet

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets

**Buenas, estoy tratando de validar un `login` en un `servlet`. Esta es la primera vez que hago uso de esto y estoy teniendo este dilema cuando presiono el botón:

**Antes de presionar el botón:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Luego de presionar el botón:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACUTALIZACIÓN:**

Este es mi `html`:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>ProyLab Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Iniciar sesión</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" name="indexLogin" action="servlets/indexLogin">
                            <div class="input-group form-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group form-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <input name="pass" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "indexLogin", urlPatterns = {"servlets/indexLogin"})
public class indexLogin extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            String usu = "admin";
            String contra = "admin";
            
            String user = request.getParameter("user");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
            
            if(user.length() > 0){
                if(usu == user){
                    if(pass.length() > 0){
                        if(pass == contra){
                            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                            out.println("alert('Ingreso exitoso')");
                            out.println("location='index.html';");
                            out.println("</script>");
                        }else{
                            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                            out.println("alert('Contraseña incorrecta')");
                            out.println("location='index.html';");
                            out.println("</script>");
                        }
                    }else{
                            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                            out.println("alert('Debe ingresar una contraseña')");
                            out.println("location='index.html';");
                            out.println("</script>");
                    }
                }else{
                    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                    out.println("alert('Usuario incorrecta')");
                    out.println("location='index.html';");
                    out.println("</script>");
                }
            }else{
                out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                out.println("alert('Debe ingresar un usuario')");
                out.println("location='index.html';");
                out.println("</script>");
            }
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Lo que intento es que mande un `alert` según las condiciones del `if` pero me sale ese error, ¿Alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar?

Adjunto captura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el atributo `action` debe tener asignado el mismo valor que asignaste en `urlPatterns` en la anotacion `@WebServlet` del archivo `indexLogin.java`.

```html
<form method="POST" action="index">
```

Actualmente lo tienes apuntando a `servlets/indexLogin`, el cual es el nombre de la clase y del archivo, pero no parece existir ningún binding del mismo nombre y, por lo tanto, te da el HTTP status code de 404.

Comment: Pues no, sigue sucediendo lo mismo

Comment: Si sigue dándote un 404, entonces posiblemente existe algún código o configuración en tu proyecto que nos falta saber para poderte decir por qué esta fallando. ¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta la captura de pantalla cuando la página de login es mostrada antes de dar click al botón Login? Otra cosa que podrías incluir es el estado actual de tu código después de las modificaciones propuestas.

Comment: Vale, he actualizado el código

Answer (score 1):

Has declarado que el servlet está en /index y el formulario lo envias a servlets/indexLogin. Prueba con poner en el servlet `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"servlets/indexLogin"})`.

Otra cosa que en el servlet ese `usu == user` no va a funcionar. Eso comprueba que sean el mismo objeto, que no es el caso. Lo que quieres es `usu.equals(user)`

Comment: Pues no, sigue sucediendo lo mismo